# cavsTxt.measureText gives different width for text based on its font family and font size

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to find the width of the text element using cavsTxt.measureText. Based on the width, I will check whether it is overflow from the parent element. I'm getting different width while changing the font-family and its size.

```
cavsElem = document.createElement("canvas");
cavsTxt =  cavsElem.getContext("2d");

//when font family as Calibri and size as 11pt
cavsTxt.font = "11pt Calibri normal";
width = cavsTxt.measureText("Clear green fluorite with tiny crystals of 
pyrite on top").width // 313.88671875

//when font family as arial  and size as 10pt
cavsTxt.font = "13px arial normal";
width = cavsTxt.measureText("Clear green fluorite with tiny crystals of 
pyrite on top").width // 285.4099426269531
```

is it behavior or an issue? how to achieve my requirement.

Comment: I think it's correct. Different fonts have different widths at the same font-size. Please compare a text written in verdana with a text written in Times (for example)

Comment: If what you want is to check if your parent element has overflow, then el.scrollWidth > el.offsetWidth. Now to your question, yes it's normal behavior: just set this font in CSS and check the size by sight. `11pt` => `14.6667px` @96dpi. So even if the font does indeed also have an influence, you are not testing the same font-sizes to begin with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you will get different size with different fonts.

Just visualize it to see what it is doing, here is a sample based on your code:

```js
var text = "Clear green fluorite with tiny crystals of pyrite on top ."
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
cavsTxt = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawText(font, x, y) {
  cavsTxt.beginPath();
  cavsTxt.font = font;
  width = cavsTxt.measureText(text).width
  
  cavsTxt.lineWidth = 20;
  cavsTxt.strokeStyle = "red";  
  cavsTxt.moveTo(x+5, y+15);
  cavsTxt.lineTo(width + x+5, y+15);
  cavsTxt.stroke();
  
  cavsTxt.fillText(cavsTxt.font, x, y);
  cavsTxt.fillText(text, x+5, y+20);
  cavsTxt.fillText(width, width+15, y+20);
}

//when font family as Calibri and size as 11pt
drawText("11pt Calibri normal", 5, 15);


//when font family as arial  and size as 10pt
drawText("13px arial normal", 5, 55);

drawText("13px arial", 5, 95);
drawText("bold 13px arial", 5, 140);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height=175 width=500 style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```

With that you can detect if the text will fit on the parent or do some special effects

Comment: But does anybody noticed that when font-weight: normal is removed. it calculates the width as 305. Modify the code "drawText("13px arial", 5, 100);" in the above sample and run. When I set font-weight as bold, it gives the same width as 285. So is it needed to pass the font weight in cavsTxt.font?

Comment: @vinoth-kumar-s I added the `drawText("13px arial",` I think the font weight is just another option for your font but not is not needed.

Comment: @vinoth-kumar-s I was playing with bold and it seem that it has to be declared at the beginning like: `"bold 13px arial"`